# Pragma message in Clang?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, message, clang, pragma

What's Clang's equivalent to `#pragma message` as used in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) and [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2.aspx)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've brought this up on the [Clang mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev), and it's in [discussion now](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2010-September/011250.html). It's subsequently been [implemented as a warning](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=114814), and hopefully soon it will be behave as it does in other compilers.

Comment: It is unfortunately implemented as a warning I'd say, but then I already replied on the mailing list.

Comment: @Mattieu M. By all means please provide an answer of your own, you are somewhat a first hand source on this :)

Comment: it is present at least since clang 3.0. And even if  the output says "1 warning generated", it doesn't fail build with `-Werror`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bcPGYr

Answer (score 0):

`#pragma message` has been [implemented recently](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=106950) - too recently for the current release (2.7), but it should be included in the forthcoming 2.8.

Comment: I am using clang from SVN and it's not present. Do you have more information? `matt@stanley:~/cpfs$ clang --version
clang version 2.9 (trunk 114802)`

Comment: Ah... looking at the code (end of `lib/Lex/Pragma.cpp`), it seems that it's being treated as one of the "Microsoft extension" features which are enabled with the `-fms-extensions` option.  (I don't have a version more recent than 2.7 to hand to try myself at the moment.)