# Is there a portable way to print a message from the C preprocessor?

Tags: printing, c-preprocessor

I would like to be able to do something like

```
#print "C Preprocessor got here!"
```

for debugging purposes.  What's the best / most portable way to do this?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The `warning` directive is probably the closest you'll get, but it's not entirely platform-independent:

```
#warning "C Preprocessor got here!"
```

AFAIK this works on most compilers except MSVC, on which you'll have to use a `pragma` directive:

```
#pragma message ( "C Preprocessor got here!" )
```

Comment: Which begs the question, can you put a directive based on a compilation flag to swap "pragma message" and "warning" somehow? For example, something like: `#ifdef _LINUX #define #preprocmsg "#warning" else #define #preprocmsg "#pragma message"`... I'll have to try that but instinct tells me the answer is no.

Comment: @Bryan: Yes. `#define WARNING(msg) _Pragma("message " #msg)`

Comment: #pragma message () is not supported by older versions of gcc (such as gcc 4.1.2, the default version on RHEL5). 

I have yet to find an appropriate equivalent for these older versions - #warning is not going to be great, as warnings are treated as errors for us generally, and we'd really like the message to be informational, rather than stop the compilation.

Comment: Issuing a warning is very inconvenient when your project compiles with -Wall by default. #pragma message doesn't have that problem.

Comment: is there someway to substitute in macro values, is that possible? Maybe something like `#warning "DEBUG="DEBUG`

Comment: @Bryan
#if defined(_WIN32) 
#pragma message ( "embrace, extend, extinguish" ) 
#else
#warning your message here
#endif

Answer (score 70):

The following are supported by [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2.aspx), and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas).

```
#pragma message("stuff")
#pragma message "stuff"
```

Clang has begun adding support recently, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796894/pragma-message-in-clang) for more.

Comment: Just for the record, Solaris Studio 12.3 (Sun C 5.12) does not support this pragma.

Comment: Works with Arduino 1.8 using Visual Studio vMicro. Thanks!

Comment: Supported by clang at least since 3.0 and by gcc since 5.1 (and in a slightly different form since 4.4.7). Even if clang says "1 warning generated", it doesn't fail build when built with `-Werror`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xoK6b8

Comment: If parentheses are omitted with MSVC, you will end up getting a compile warning instead of a preprocessor message. Both work for GCC, but parentheses can be omitted for GCC.

Answer (score 15):

Most C compilers will recognize a `#warning` directive, so

```
 #warning "Got here"
```

There's also the standard '#error' directive,

```
 #error "Got here"
```

While all compilers support that, it'll also stop the compilation/preprocessing.

Answer (score 14):

You might want to try: `#pragma message("Hello World!")`

Answer (score 11):

```
#pragma message("foo")
```

works great. Also wouldn't stop compilation even if you use -Werror

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with numbers or other values? It says it expects a string, but I would like to print out what a numeric `#define` is calculated to be.

Comment: @AaronFranke During the preprocessor step, all defines should be ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use comments plus a shell script to process them. This takes some discipline (or a shell script which catches typos).

For example, I add comments formatted `//TODO` and then a shell script which collects all of them into a report.

For more complex use cases, you can try to write your own simple preprocessor. For example, you could edit your sources as `*.c2` files. The simple preprocessor would read the source, look for `//TODO`, and write `printf("TODO ...")` into the output `*.c` file.