# Printing something with C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a portable way to print a message from the C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826832/is-there-a-portable-way-to-print-a-message-from-the-c-preprocessor)

When navigating through a large code base, it is sometimes difficult to guess what is defined and what is not. Therefore, I want to print something at compilation time. For example:

```
#ifdef SOME_DEFINE
// I want a preprocessor to print something here so that 
//  I can know whether SOME_DEFINE is defined or not
#endif
```

Is this possible to do with **C**?
I saw something called `#error` somewhere. Maybe that is my only option, or not?

Comment: lots of questions about this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826832/is-there-a-portable-way-to-print-a-message-from-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: Better than `#error` is `#warning`, if the preprocessor supports it.

Answer (score 1):

For MS Visual C++:

```
#define __PRINT(str) __pragma(message(str))
```

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about the `#error` directive is that it works even if it is not supported!

If it's supported, the compiler tells you `"error: #error"` and if it is not supported, the compiler tells you `"invalid preprocessing directive"`.  Either way it's a fatal error and compilation stops, and the compiler tells you which was the offending line.