# C pragma that writes text into a file during compilation

Tags: c, compilation, pragma

Is it possible to write text into a file during compilation?

For example:

```
#ifdef ICC
#pragma write("log.txt", "ICC was used to compile %s", __FILE__)
function_optimized_for_icc()
#endif
```

Comment: Don't see it for Visual Studio or gcc. gcc has `#pragma message string` though. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826832/is-there-a-portable-way-to-print-a-message-from-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: @RetiredNinja and @lserni, there are lots of different files to be compiled and there are lots of different compile flags for each compiler (`xlc`, `icc`, `gcc`). I wonder if there is a simple way to write the flags into a file. Redirecting compilation output and parsing it, is also a solution but it will be better if the parsing phase can be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, but in most compilers you can easily use a pragma to write a message to the console (`#pragma warn`, `#pragma message` etc.).

At that point you can just > redirect or `tee` the output to a file and filter it appropriately.