# Adding compile time message from source file

Tags: c++, c, compilation

Is it possible in any available C/C++ compiler to print messages from source file when I compile the source file (its okay if it doesn't print it while linking) . I will have to embed the message into the source file.

(To make it clearer, using a printf would print the message in run time. I do not want to print the message in run time.)

I am aware that the message can be put in a Makefile ( which is what I have been doing so far). However, I would really like if the message can be put in source file itself.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826832/is-there-a-portable-way-to-print-a-message-from-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: If your compiler supports it, you could use a `#warning` preprocessor directive, but bear in mind that the message will be displayed as a warning.

Comment: Any particular C compiler?  Have a look at #pragma message if it is Microsoft or gcc.  Note that the syntax is different for MS and gcc

Comment: Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero compilers also support `#pragma message`

Answer (score 1):

The C99 standard defines an `#error` preprocessor directive which can be used for this task:

§6.10.5:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> > `#error` pp-tokens<sub>opt</sub> new-line
>
> causes the implementation to produce a diagnostic message that includes the speciﬁed
> sequence of preprocessing tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers have `#pragma message`, which prints a user-defined message in the compiler's diagnostics output.