# How check if header guard is defined

Tags: c++, header-files, precompiled-headers

I have these files that were given to me to solve and I have some doubts about header guard.

1. In `testGuards.h`, there is a define like `__HEADER_GUILD_SAFEBOX__`, but the `#ifdef` asks if `__GUILD_SAFEBOX__` is defined, so I don't know if this `#ifdef` should ask about  `__HEADER_GUILD_SAFEBOX__` instead of  `__GUILD_SAFEBOX__`.
2. In `testCpp.h` I ask if `__GUILD_SAFEBOX__` is already defined, but, as far I know, it is already defined in `testGuards.h`, but here (in cpp), we never enter into the `#ifdef`, and I not know, how to know if is not defined, and if not defined, then define it.

I have 2 codes.

testGuards.h

```
#ifndef __HEADER_GUILD_SAFEBOX__
#define __HEADER_GUILD_SAFEBOX__

#include "stdafx.h"

#ifdef __GUILD_SAFEBOX__
[...]
#endif
```

testCpp.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#ifdef __GUILD_SAFEBOX__
#include "../common/tables.h"
[...]
#endif
```

Comment: Identifiers (including macro names) containing a double underscore are [reserved for the implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/501250) (compiler and standard library). **You should not use them.**

Comment: I think you are not meant to put stdafx.h anywhere other than the first line of the file

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks so much, is very useful to me, I readed all.
I changed __HEADER_GUILD_SAFEBOX__ for __GUILD_SAFEBOX_H and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could print a message, as a header is included. After that you can manually/automatically check whatever you want.

Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826832/is-there-a-portable-way-to-print-a-message-from-the-c-preprocessor):

The warning directive is probably the closest you'll get, but it's not entirely platform-independent:

```
#warning "C Preprocessor got here!"
```

AFAIK this works on most compilers except MSVC, on which you'll have to use a pragma directive:

```
#pragma message ( "C Preprocessor got here!" )
```

Comment: I used it, but at first it did not work, because I never really defined well the header.