# How to print line number in preprocessor?

Tags: gcc, clang

[Is there a portable way to print a message from the C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826832/is-there-a-portable-way-to-print-a-message-from-the-c-preprocessor)

gcc preprocessor can print messages. How to print the source code line numbers in the messages? Thanks.

Comment: `#warning` and `#pragma message` precede the message with the line number, is that not sufficient?

Comment: Could you show the exact text to demonstrate the effect?

Comment: For example, `#pragma message "This is a message"` makes the compiler output `foo.c:4:9: note: #pragma message: This is a message`, where `4` is the line number where the `#pragma` appears.  (And `9` is the column where the message begins.)